# Running ASP.NET Apps on IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I have a .NET 2.0 ASP.NET app built using VS2013.  It runs fine on IIS7.5/Windows7 in a .NET 2 Classic Pipeline App Pool.  However when I try to run it on IIS6/Windows 2003 server I get 404 Page Not Found.

I have installed .NET 2 (+SP2) on the Windows2003 server of course, as well as registering with IIS using aspnet_regiis -i. I have set the framework version of the app accordingly. I have checked the file system permissions and confirmed that the IUSR_* account can access the web app files.  The authentication type for the app is 'None'.  The default page list includes Default.aspx which is correct.

It's seems ASP.NET isn't kicking in, what am I missing?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are accessing correct url? Also check if all required MIME types are registered in IIS server. Try putting simple html/aspx test page in created site/application and browsing it. Some screenshots from your iis may help to find out whats wrong there.

Comment: Yes, definitely the correct URL and the ASPX type is mapped to the correct aspnet_isapi.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had neglected to allow the ASP.NET Web Service Extension:

[IIS 6.0 Serves .html and .asp, but not .aspx](http://forums.iis.net/t/1134035.aspx)

[image]